# Not able to apply any of the queries in SQL Server 2008 R2 in CSV file?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I imported a `.csv` file into SQL Server 2008 R2. I'm trying any of the queries in SQL Server 2008 R2, the queries are not running, I get errors like

> Invalid column name

All the columns are of type `Varchar`, when trying to do cast and conversion it's also not taking it.

[This is the data in the csv file(table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IkBR.png)

Comment: Did you import the data into the **correct** database? How did you do the import?? Are you querying the correct database??

Comment: Yes I imported in correct way. First I selected the database, then go to task- import file- selected flat file source and process goes on. And also m querying the correct data the database which is imported one.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your columns - most likely from the CSV import.

Your querying

```
SELECT YEAR(Date) AS YEAR 
FROM [Covid -19 Data]
```

but the **first column** in your table is called `"Date` with leading double quotes....

Furthermore, calling a column `Date` is a horribly bad practice - it's unclear what kind of date it is, and it also collides with the **reserved T-SQL keyword** called `DATE` - try to use **more descriptive** and more meaningful column names - `HireDate`, or `BirthDate`, or `SampleDate` or whatever makes sense in your case.....

Comment: When I imported csv file to sql server it shows double quotes only, have tried with number of queries but didnot work any of one query. And all the columns are in varchar not able to even convert the columns. Tried your query too showing the error:- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Answer (score 0):

Columns should never have spaces even if your [] brace your names. Columns in a table done have to be human readable, only having supporting meta data to their meanings. Fix your table column names and retry your SQL.